# xcode 5 crashing after update to yosemite developer preview

Tags: xcode, storyboard, xcode5, osx-yosemite

I have updated today my iMac to yosemite developer preview. Everything is working fine except my xcode 5.0. If i open a project in xcode 5.0 and then try to view the storyboard it crash. I  reinstall it after deleting the old one but no use. It's still crashing.

While storyboard working fine on xcode 5.1.1 but i am facing some issue there like i am increasing the size of my tabbar it's size is creasing perfectly on iPhone build but not on iPad build.

can any body help me in either case.

Comment: My Xcode 5.1.1 crash when dragging an IBOutlet or IBAction from Storyboard to the code. Already reported it to Apple - hoping that they fix this in an update soon. I can't resist trying Yosemite UI and I'm actually loving it now :)

Comment: Likewise, same issue as @schystz here. I don't think it is likely to be fixed soon or at all. I am writing outlets and actions by hand and connecting from code to storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I find Xcode 5 more stable than 6 regarding storyboard crashes.

@LpLrich from the comments above is correct, writing the `IBOutlets` and `IBActions` by hand and wiring up in the reverse direction to storyboard works for now.

Things should get better with the public beta coming soon.

Answer (score 0):

With Yosemite it's better to use Xcode 6. Download it. And don't forget that all of this is "Developer preview" - you should be ready to face with some issues.

Comment: An issue regarding Xcode 6 is that the developer tools will break your capistrano deploys if you are also a Rails developer. There's several extraneous bugs which preclude migration to Xcode 6, be aware of these if you develop more than just for iOS.

Comment: And I've experienced this same issue on Xcode 6, as have others eg http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1741694

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are using pre-release software. Xcode 5 was not made for OSX Yosemite. You can still use it but it won't be fully optimized. I recommend getting Xcode 6 which IS optimized for Yosemite and won't crash as much as Xcode 5. I have the same problem and when I switched to Xcode 6, crashes occur less often now. Hope this helps!